# AJAX POST METHOD

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi I'm using ajax for posting the data in to database, I'm using php as server background for posting the data in mysql database, for

```
 Ex: $name = $_POST['name'];
 $query = "INSERT INTO table('name') VALUES ('".$name."');
 $result = mysql_query($query)
```

when the user click on the submit button, i just made a onlick function of ajax post_data(), 
so what i need is i want the value in the textbox so that i can pass it to ajax, how to get the value of the textbox

```
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "name=?"; (how to get the name enter in the text box)
http.open("POST", url, true);


http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: I think your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You may want to take some time to learn more about that before progressing further with your project.

Comment: Yep, bigtime injection vulnerability.

Comment: Then how can i prevent it from SQL injection, Plz let me know, what i need to do

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Your quotes in the PHP sample don't match.

Answer (score -2):

You can give the textbox and id.

And then using this code

```
var textValue = document.getElementById("textboxid").value;
```

you can get as well set the value in the textbox.

Comment: Needs [encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't send $POST vars directly to the db. Look up sanitization.

```
var url = "get_data.php";
var validValue=validate(document.getElementById('textboxid').value) ;
var params = "name=?"+validValue;


http.open("POST", url, true);


<!-- assuming your text box is-->
<input type =textbox id="textboxid">
```

**And don't forget to sanitize at the server side too.**

Comment: Needs encoding for HTTP transport too, and `validate()` is undefined.

Comment: If the data is important to be encoded in http transport, I would say the sequence is clientValidate->clientEncode->serverDecode->serverReValidate..Perhaps even use checksum. Why? Even enocoded streams can be tampered by the network. I'd  rather stick to SSL for such sensitive information.

Comment: Encoding != Encrypting. If the text box valid includes, for instance, the character `&` then when the data is processed it (and everything following it) is going to be chopped off.

Comment: At first I thought you were just stating the obvious while trying to outsmart everyone by offending them. I thought you meant encryption when you called it encoding. You are correct.

Answer (score -3):

`var params = "name=?"; (how to get the name enter in the text box)`

you can try:

`var params = "name="+document.getElementById('theTextBoxId').value;`

Comment: Needs [encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: I thought the `post` method is sent as a part of the request body and doesn't use the query string?

Comment: It is sent as the request body but, unless you start playing with the Content-Type, still uses the same encoding.

Comment: can you please give me a real example or a link about GET and POST use the same encoding method?

Comment: taken from your link: "(when the value of method is "post"). The default value for this attribute is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"." and not https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Are you suggesting that the `encodeURIComponent` **function** doesn't prepare data for the application/x-www-form-urlencoded **MIME type** ?